# Fighting aliens in small frontier town during the later half of the 1800's

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I read the book in the 1980s, I don't remember the main character but I think was a Male Protagonist fighting Aliens in small town during the later half of the 1800's, typical Frontier town.

I remember the weapon that the character commandeered and it took him some time to figure out the trigger mechanism. It required him to hold the tear drop shaped weapon between his body and arm, I think the trigger was combination of thought/will/and nerve impulse?

I think the word "Hunter" is in the title of the book?

The Movie "Cowboys and Aliens" reminded me of the book.

It was in English and had a nice picture cover. The picture looked like a Frontier town in Twilight with other details?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Please try to add anything that may help identification. Review this [**checklist**](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337). What language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title **next time**, in the interim I've edited it for you.

Comment: Sounds like the inspiration for the 2011 popcorn movie [*Cowboys & Aliens.*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0409847/)

Comment: Correct. I added my comment about Cowboys and Aliens, that was edited out.

Comment: *Cowboys and Aliens* was based on a graphic novel of the same name..although Steven John Busti filed a lawsuit claiming copyright infringement. He stated he wrote a preview for his story Cowboys and Aliens in 1994, which was published in the April 1995 issue of Bizarre Fantasy #1.

Comment: Not Boxleitner's *Frontier Earth* by any chance? - https://www.amazon.com/Frontier-Earth-Bruce-Boxleitner/dp/0441005896/ref=pd_sim_14_2?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=0441005896&pd_rd_r=Q3TJF4JJ4C3YCN1HTNQ4&pd_rd_w=hONRB&pd_rd_wg=7tUmw&psc=1&refRID=Q3TJF4JJ4C3YCN1HTNQ4